# Where are the full site settings stored?

Tags: full-site-editing, theme.json

When making changes in the full site editor, where are the settings actually stored?

When searching for this I get a gazillion results saying the settings are stored in `theme.json`, but this can't be right. If I check the `theme.json` file right after making changes in the full site editor the changes are not reflected in `theme.json`. I have to export the theme in the full site editing first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make modifications to templates the new HTML of the template is saved as a custom post type with the `wp_template` post type. This is then used instead of the version stored in the theme directory. The same is true template parts, except the post type for those is `wp_template_part`.

When you modify global styles the `styles` and `settings` properties of `theme.json` are copied to to the database, this time as a post with the `wp_global_styles` post type, with your changes applied to this copy.

Comment: Thanks. It was that last part about global styles I was concerned about. Found it when searching for `wp_global_styles` in the phpMyAdmin. Kind of weird that the changes are written to the DB and not the theme.json file. Why is that?

Comment: Reading and writing from files is slower and theme files are all overwritten whenever there’s a theme update. It would also make it impossible to reset to defaults.

Comment: Thank you very much @JacobPeattie for detailed answer.. one more thing for future WP google-er like me.. if you use customizer.php to style (easier css) then it's saved in `custom_css` post type.. good thing it's both outputed on front