# Editing templates in an FSE theme

Tags: full-site-editing

If I edit a template file in a FSE theme, why don't I see the changes in the backend Site Editor or frontend?

I am assuming that I should...?

[image]

For example, the highlighted block here I copied to further up the file but I don't see any changes at all anywhere...

Sorry, I know there isn't much information here, I'm not sure what else I can add.

Comment: Well the point of FSE is that you could make this change in the editor, but if the template has been edited in the editor already then it’s saved to the database and that is used instead. You’ll need to make this change in the editor or make it in the file and then reset the template in the editor so that the template is loaded from the file.

Comment: Ahaa, that makes sense. So if the template has been customised, only further changes can be made in the Site Editor but I can 'Clear Customisations' and reset it back to the theme version which would load the template file from server. That's great and just what I was seeking clarification on - thanks for that @JacobPeattie

Comment: Yep that’s all correct. I’ve previously answered with a little bit more information on where the data is stored here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/414905/where-are-the-full-site-settings-stored/414906#414906

Comment: Perfect, that's great, thank you :)